# Updating EditText LayoutParams from SurfaceView thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-edittext, surfaceview, layoutparams

I have a EditText object created in the main activity in onCreate. I need to be able to change the layout parameters from a SurfaceView thread. Currently I am getting this error:

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I also tried setting the layout parameters from a UIHandler but I get the same error. I am really new to Android dev, so I would greatly appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can use `runOnUiThread` to update the UI from a different thread. e.g.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    textView.setText("Hello");
  }
});
```